# Change Rating Bar value from integer

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to create a rating bar that showing score of the user (Ex: 80 will become 4 stars).
I dont allow the user to change it, so i think no listener will be needed.
Now i know theres a function name `getRating` but how to use it?
All i want is get a value (Ex : 60) and the user will see 3stars in my ratingbar.
Thanks :D

**Solved. i can use `SetRating` to take an integer value to my Rating Bar**

Comment: Get the score, convert it to the rating (Ex 60 is 3) and change the drawable for 3 stars only out of 5 stars.

Comment: http://androidorigin.blogspot.ch/2010/10/android-ratingbar-demo-program.html

Comment: @AamirShah i dont think it will be a good idea, because i have a complex code...
Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @rshetty01 Can you show me the code?i have googling it but i still dont get the tutorial nor the syntax :D
Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well android have already a [`RatingBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html).

Follow the tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/) for some initial concepts.

you can set the  max number of stars to show:

[`setNumStars()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setNumStars%28int%29)

you can set the maximum value of Rating Bar like:

[`setMax()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setMax%28int%29)

So when you set 5 as number stars and set 100 as max of your Ratings, system will automatically show 4 stars against score of 80 and will show 3 stars against 60, So let the system decide how many stars to show against your score.

Comment: [Here](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) is a tutorial to customize `RatingBar`.

Comment: Thanks, i understand both of them, but the case is : how to do it?what is the syntax? lets say that i have an integer with value 100. How to connect that int to my ratingbar.

Comment: Sorry but your tutorial is not helping, the problem is not about customizing like that.
Thanks :D

Comment: doesn't this works? [`ratingBar.setRating(100);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setRating(float))